# How does the "jimport" function from "etherpad" work?

Tags: java, javascript, html

In etherpad's source I've seen code like:

```
jimport(java.util.Date, "JDate");
```

But it doesn't seem like some kind of javascript standard.

How is it done?

Comment: Sorry. Misread your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're looking at the [etherpad](http://etherpad.org) source. There they defined a [helper function](http://google.com/codesearch#1mzKPhR856Y/infrastructure/framework-src/preamble.js&q=_JimportSinglePackage&type=cs&l=310) named `jimport`.

As mentioned, etherpad uses Rhino as its Javascript engine, which have Java available at his fingertips. So it is enough to make

```
file = java.io.File
```

in order to "import" it.

This function uses the helper function `_jimportSinglePackage`, to inject the Java package into the local Javascript scope.

This function receives the package name, and the global scope to which it'll inject the package to, and given `a.b.c` its essentially calling `globalscope[c] = a.b.c`, in order to `import` this Java package.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to load Java libraries in JavaScript is highly-dependent on which server-side JavaScript framework you're using.

Loading Java is definitely supported by [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). From the docs:

```
js> importPackage(java.io)
js> File
[JavaClass java.io.File]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use Java classes from JavaScript:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(new java.util.Date());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See [Call a Java method from Javascript](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html) for more details.